# Laravel if else statement

Tags: laravel, if-statement, domdocument

I´m trying to output 2 different things. For example: if title is greater then 0 then do this. If not, do this.

I'm using **DomDocument & Laravel 5.4**

In my controller:

```
$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
```

To output on the page:

```
@foreach ($title as $node)
 @if(!$node > 0)
  {{'No title'}}
   @else
    {{$node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL}} <br />
  @endif
@endforeach
```

The problem: If there is a title it displays the title. If there is no title it shows nothing. I want to display: "No title".

Why isn't this working?

Comment: replace {{'No title'}} with No title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
@if (condition)
    No title
@else
```

But I doubt `!$node > 0` part does what you want.

It's better to use ternary operator:

```
@foreach ($title as $node)
    {{ empty($node->nodeValue) ? '' : $node->nodeValue }} <br />
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I've discovered that the website i'm testing my project on has <title> tags but it's empty. So i've changed empty($node) to empty($node->nodeValue) and it worked like a charm! Please update your answer so i can mark this answer as correct.